# How to determin how much RAM is needed to process a certain size of data?

Tags: r, data.table

For example, if I have a 2 GB `csv` file, how much free RAM is needed to process it in `R`, (specificly `data.table`)? On the other side, if I have a 3 GB *available* memory, what's the largest data I could process using this computer? I couldn't find any calculation method on this; according to your experience, how do you calculate it?

Comment: That's an implementation issue. For example, Revolution R's implementation isn't restricted by the available RAM.

Comment: In my experience, it is too hard to calculate this kind of thing.

Comment: Columns and rows also have different overhead which means that the same amount of data will take different amounts of RAM for long, narrow tables vs wider, shorter ones

Comment: I'd say a good rule of thumb is that you need 3 times the dataset size in amount of RAM. This will enable you to load it, and perform operations and analyses on it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks! Is that roughly true that wider (short) table takes more memory than narrow (long) one?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I've read your answers to other linked questions - quite informative. Thank you.